# Package org.apache.tools.ant missing

Tags: apache, ant, javac

I have an issue while trying to compile a java file. 
When I call

```
javac MyClass.java
```

some errors occur, all referring to a missing `org.apache.tools.ant` package...

I've got ant installed (in Ubuntu 14.04) but not this package.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the link shared will solve your problem.

http://www.j2eekart.com/2014/12/compile-run-java-program-using-ant.html

Check it.